# Does the Android Support Library duplicate code in each app?

Tags: android

I have seen the question [How Android Support Library work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641669/how-android-support-library-work) however it does not answer the question of whether each app that uses the same support library causes the duplication of code, and thus uses up space on the device.  For example, if the support library is 1MB, and 7 apps use it, does that use an extra 1MB or 7MB, or some other amount?

Also, if my app uses only part of the support library, does all of it need to be installed on the device?

Answer (score 2):

yes each app has its own support library and if you use pro guard or the new `minify` in android studio it does not install the whole library, otherwise yes it does

Comment: Can someone please post a source for this information?

Comment: Everything you said in your answer

Comment: Why can't android use the linux "shared library" concept for the Support Library so each app wouldn't have to duplicate it? ( http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html )

Comment: there is no source for the first part, thats just how libraries work on android. As for the minify look at update 0.14.0 here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system